# Fading transition between bootstrap contextual classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the background of a bootstrap 4 table row (`table-danger`). And the slowly (1 sec) fade the background back to its original color (white).

The closest I have gotten is adding the class and then removing it. However, this creates a abrupt change in color. I would like the background color to instantly turn red and then slowly fade to white.

```
$('#row_1').addClass("table-danger") //Turn background red instantly
$('#row_1').removeClass("table-danger") //I want this to fade into a white background. Not just an immediate change.
```

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gc85wfh9/8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add transitions for the `background-color` property of all the elements you're changing. In your case, to `<tr>`s, `<td>`s and `<th>`s.

```css
.table th, 
.table td,
.table tr {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

See it [working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/rjouk6gt/).

Comment: Thanks Andrei. This almost works but it fades into red and back to white. I am only looking to fade into white. The initial red background change should be instant. Edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: I updated the example. Now it no longer works on click. It enters with danger background and fades to white over 1 second from page load.